# How to multiple columns with multiple values into new rows while keeping other data R?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, tidyr, delimiter

I have a dataset in which some columns contain multiple values that are seperated by ";".

Excerpt from dataset:

```
deal_ids<- c("3020269MM","3137144MM"
             ,"3087938MM","3010412MM"
             ,"3054942MM","441272MM")

acquirer_ids<- c("05MW2D-E; 060Y79-E; 07HJ6C-E; 0FT58G-E"
                 ,"0GVB8N-E","05PYR2-E; 0H2MMQ-E","0H3CG6-E",
                 "0JK2T2-E", "05G8Z3-E; 05L112-E")

acquirer_names <- c("Cushman & Wakefield, Inc.; Ontario Teachers' Private Capital; Pacific Alliance Equity Partners Ltd.; TPG Real Estate Partners",
        "Jiangsu Aukura Smart Transmission Engineering Tech Co., Ltd.",
        "City of Shanghai; Hotels & Préférence SARL",
        "Business Empire Investments Ltd.",
        "Profit Sky Corp Ltd",
        "BAIN CAPITAL LLC; Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.")

acquirer_ownership <-c("Subsidiary; Subsidiary; Subsidiary; Subsidiary",
                       "Public Company",
                       "Government; Subsidiary",
                       "Subsidiary",
                       "Subsidiary",
                       "Private Company; Private Company")

acquirer_country <- c("United States; Canada; Hong Kong; United States",
                      "China (People's Republic)",
                      "China (People's Republic); France",
                      "British Virgin Islands",
                      "Hong Kong",
                      "United States; China (People's Republic)")

acquirer_size<-c("Big",
                 "Big",
                 "Small",
                 "Big",
                 "Small",
                 "Small")

acquirer_secondary_industry <- c("(Real Estate and Rental and Leasing); (-); (-); (-)",
NA, "(-); (-)", "Finance and Insurance", NA, "(-); (Manufacturing; Manufacturing; Manufacturing);" )


acquirer_synopsis <-
c("Cushman & Wakefield Inc, a portfolio company of Pacific Alliance Equity Partners Ltd, TPG Real Estate Partners and Teachers' Private Capital, acquired 20 VIC Management Inc for an undisclosed amount. The acquisition would enhance Cushman & Wakefield Inc's service offerings and expands its market presence in Canada. As part of the transaction, George Buckles and Randy Scharf, co-founders of 20 VIC Management Inc, would join Cushman & Wakefield Inc as executive managing directors. Employees of 20 VIC Management Inc would join Cushman & Wakefield Inc. Following the transaction, 20 VIC Management Inc would operate under the banner of Cushman & Wakefield Inc. 20 VIC Management Inc is located in Toronto, Canada and provides real estate management services."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
, "Jiangsu Aukura Smart Transmission Engineering Tech Co Ltd acquired 284 Partners LLC for an undisclosed amount. 284 Partners LLC is located in Ann Arbor, Michigan, United States and provides intellectual property consultancy."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
, "Hotels & Préférence SARL, a subsidiary of Groupe du Louvre SASU which is ultimately owned by the City of Shanghai, acquired 2Lnet SAS, trading as TemptingPlaces, for an undisclosed amount. The transaction is expected to support Hotels & Préférence SARL's growth and development strategy. Founded by Laurence Onfroy, 2Lnet SAS provides an online platform for hotel bookings. It is based in Paris, France."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
, "Business Empire Investments Ltd, a subsidiary of SEA Holdings Ltd, acquired 33 Old Broad Street Investment Co Ltd from 33 Old Broad Street Holdings Ltd, for GBP258 million (US$332.6 million) in cash. The transaction was funded from Business Empire Investments Ltd's existing cash resources and a term loan facility. 33 Old Broad Street Investment Co Ltd is located in United kingdom and holds and manages properties. The deal was closed as originally expected by July 17, 2017."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
, "Profit Sky Corp Ltd, a subsidiary of Admiral Colour Ltd, ultimately owned by Asia Cassava Resources Holdings Ltd, acquired 338 Apartment (BVI) Ltd from 338 Apartment Holdings (BVI) Ltd, for HKD1.1 billion (US$140.1 million) in cash and assumed liabilities. Under the terms of agreement, HKD570 million (US$72.6 million) was paid in cash and HKD530 million (US$67.5 million) was paid in assumed liabilities. The acquisition was funded through existing cash resources and bank borrowings. The acquisition includes a 25-storey commercial building with hotel license located at 338 Queen's Road Central, Sheung Wan, Hong Kong. 338 Apartment (BVI) Ltd is located in Hong Kong, and owns and operates apartments. The deal was subject to shareholders approval and was expected to be completed on October 08, 2018. On July 03, 2018, Asia Cassava Resources Holdings Ltd announced that despatch of the circular had been postponed from June 30, 2018 to July 31, 2018. On July 31, 2018, Asia Cassava Resources Holdings Ltd announced that despatch of the circular has been postponed from July 30, 2018 to August 31, 2018. On August 21, 2018, it was announced that an extraordinary general meeting would be held on September 06, 2018. On September 06, 2018, shareholders of Asia Cassava Resources Holdings Ltd have approved the acquisition of 338 Apartment (BVI) Ltd in Extraordinary General Meeting. The deal was closed as expected on October 8, 2018."
, "Bain Capital LLC terminated its agreement to acquire 3Com Corp for US$2.1 billion in cash. Under the terms of the agreement, each share of 3Com Corp was to be acquired for US$5.30.  This represented about a 44% premium over 3Com Corp's September 27, 2007 close price of US$3.68. With the acquisition, 3Com Corp aimed to better position itself as a global networking leader. As part of the transaction, Huawei Technologies Co Ltd was going to gain a minority stake in 3Com Corp and become its strategic partner. Based in Marlborough, Massachusetts, 3Com Corp provides secure, converged voice and data networking solutions. On February 20, 2008, 3Com along with affiliates of Bain Capital and Huawei Technologies had withdrawn their joint filing to the Committee on Foreign Investment in the U.S. concerning the parties' proposed merger. The termination is due to the U.S. Government’s Committee on Foreign Investment in the United States saying it intended to take action to prohibit that transaction.")


example_df_2<-
        data.frame(
                deal_ids,
                acquirer_ids,
                acquirer_names,
                acquirer_ownership,
                acquirer_country,
                acquirer_size,
                acquirer_secondary_industry,
                acquirer_synopsis)
```

My goal to "break-up" all these cells across the dataframe. Other cells that dont have multiple values in the row under consideration are supposed to just copy the previous value.

So far I have tried with dplyr and its seperate_rows.
This does not work:

```
first_try <- example_df %>%
        separate_rows(`deal_ids`,
                      `acquirer_ids`,
                      acquirer_names,
                      `acquirer_ownership`,
                      `acquirer_country`,
                      acquirer_size,
acquirer_secondary_industry,
                acquirer_synopsis)
```

For this reason I applied it in a loop column for column:

```
cols <- colnames(example_df)
for(col in cols) {
        print(col)
        example_df <- separate_rows_(example_df, col,sep = ";")
        example_df <- example_df %>%  mutate(across(where(is.character), str_trim))
        example_df <- unique(example_df)
        gc()
}
```

This however gives me wrong combinations of values - eg: first line of dataframe:

[image: Wrong result]

How do I solve this?
I want that the delimited data goes with its delimited "partner-data".

EDIT 2 - Special Difficulties:

Difficulty 1) Note that, some of the cells in the dataframe contain delimited Data in paranthesis. These should not be separated but kept as they are.
E.g.: Text1;(Text2;Text2);Text3
should result in 3 different lines and not in 4

Difficulty 2) Some cells, contain more delimited datapoints than others.
E.g.:
Column 1: Text1;Text2
Column 2: OtherText
Column 3: ExampleText1; ExampleText2;ExampleText3

In this case, the expected output should just "copy down" the latest value in the shorter columns.

Kind regards

Comment: the dput/sample is not running.  giving error `Error in data.frame(deal_ids, acquirer_ids, acquirer_names, acquirer_ownership,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 6`

Comment: Thanks, I will correct it

Comment: Corrected the input example

Comment: I have simplified your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67885176/2884859).  Let's wait.

Comment: Amazing how you could rephrase my question in a more valuable way. Thanks a lot, I think the way you put it, pretty much nails the actual problems. As I am new here, and also a learner, is it legitimate to ask for explanation under the suggested solutions?

Comment: Didn't the answer serve the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

example_df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), str_split, pattern = "; ")) %>%
  pmap_dfr(tibble)
```

result:

```
   deal_ids  acquirer_ids acquirer_names                                   acquirer_ownersh~ acquirer_country       acquirer_size
   <chr>     <chr>        <chr>                                            <chr>             <chr>                  <chr>        
 1 3020269MM 05MW2D-E     Cushman & Wakefield, Inc.                        Subsidiary        United States          Big          
 2 3020269MM 060Y79-E     Ontario Teachers' Private Capital                Subsidiary        Canada                 Big          
 3 3020269MM 07HJ6C-E     Pacific Alliance Equity Partners Ltd.            Subsidiary        Hong Kong              Big          
 4 3020269MM 0FT58G-E     TPG Real Estate Partners                         Subsidiary        United States          Big          
 5 3137144MM 0GVB8N-E     Jiangsu Aukura Smart Transmission Engineering T~ Public Company    China (People's Repub~ Big          
 6 3087938MM 05PYR2-E     City of Shanghai                                 Government        China (People's Repub~ Small        
 7 3087938MM 0H2MMQ-E     Hotels & Préférence SARL                         Subsidiary        France                 Small        
 8 3010412MM 0H3CG6-E     Business Empire Investments Ltd.                 Subsidiary        British Virgin Islands Big          
 9 3054942MM 0JK2T2-E     Profit Sky Corp Ltd                              Subsidiary        Hong Kong              Small        
10 441272MM  05G8Z3-E     BAIN CAPITAL LLC                                 Private Company   United States          Small        
11 441272MM  05L112-E     Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.                    Private Company   China (People's Repub~ Small
```

explanation: split each column at `;` . This will make each column a list.

```
  deal_ids  acquirer_ids acquirer_names acquirer_ownership acquirer_country acquirer_size
  <list>    <list>       <list>         <list>             <list>           <list>       
1 <chr [1]> <chr [4]>    <chr [4]>      <chr [4]>          <chr [4]>        <chr [1]>    
2 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>      <chr [1]>          <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>    
3 <chr [1]> <chr [2]>    <chr [2]>      <chr [2]>          <chr [2]>        <chr [1]>    
4 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>      <chr [1]>          <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>    
5 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>      <chr [1]>          <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>    
6 <chr [1]> <chr [2]>    <chr [2]>      <chr [2]>          <chr [2]>        <chr [1]>
```

`pmap_dfr` takes rows of this data.frame and pass it to `tibble` and binds everything into data.frame.

Comment: Hi & thank you very much for your reply. Can you maybe explain your answer code? Furthermore, I noticed when applying to my bigger dataset that I have sometimes the Issue that certain columns contain more data seperated by ";" than the rest of the columns. Any Idea on how to deal with that?

Comment: Edit: I found that these cells are in the form of: value1;(value2;value2);value3 which might be the reason why it can lead to a mismatch. How can I amend your code in a way so it does not consider delimter that are enclosed in brackets?

Comment: yeah this can most certainly cause a problem. Include this (and all other possibilities)  in your example data set and give expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I updated the example now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit. How would you amend your answer if you had a "mismatch" in seperated values in the columns? E.g. Column 1 has 2 separated values and colum 4 has 6 separated values - here the last value of column 1 should be copied. Following your suggestion I get the following answer: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
* Size 2: Existing data.
* Size 3: Column `Acquirer ID`.
i Only values of size one are recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Eddy, since your sample data is too complex to understand and further based on your comments on [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67885176/how-to-separate-rows-in-case-of-a-complex-data) I propose you this solution in `tidyverse` but in two steps.

1. First replace all your delimiters outside `()` by `;;` and mane your data say `input1`
2. Thereafter using `purrr::map` you can get desired output.

To demonstrate

```r
input <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  col_1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Col_2 = c("Text_A;Text_B","Text_C","Text_D;(Text_E;Text_F)"),
  Col_3 = c("Text_1", "Text_2;Text_3", "Text_4"),
  Col_4 = c("Text_a;(Text_b;Text_c);(Text_d;Text_dd)","Text_e","Text_f;Text_g")
)
input
  col_1                  Col_2         Col_3                                   Col_4
1     A          Text_A;Text_B        Text_1 Text_a;(Text_b;Text_c);(Text_d;Text_dd)
2     B                 Text_C Text_2;Text_3                                  Text_e
3     C Text_D;(Text_E;Text_F)        Text_4                           Text_f;Text_g
```

#### Approach suggested

```
library(tidyverse)
#step-1
input1 <- input %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~gsub(";(?![^(]*\\))", ";;", ., perl=TRUE)))

input1
  col_1                   Col_2          Col_3                                     Col_4
1     A          Text_A;;Text_B         Text_1 Text_a;;(Text_b;Text_c);;(Text_d;Text_dd)
2     B                  Text_C Text_2;;Text_3                                    Text_e
3     C Text_D;;(Text_E;Text_F)         Text_4                            Text_f;;Text_g

#step-2
map_dfc(input1, ~{max(map_int(input1, ~ length(unlist(str_split(., ';;'))) )) -> l1
  length(unlist(str_split(.x, ';;'))) -> tmp
  c(unlist(str_split(.x, ';;')), rep(NA, times = l1 - tmp))
}) %>% fill(everything())
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   col_1 Col_2           Col_3  Col_4           
#>   <chr> <chr>           <chr>  <chr>           
#> 1 A     Text_A          Text_1 Text_a          
#> 2 B     Text_B          Text_2 (Text_b;Text_c) 
#> 3 C     Text_C          Text_3 (Text_d;Text_dd)
#> 4 C     Text_D          Text_4 Text_e          
#> 5 C     (Text_E;Text_F) Text_4 Text_f          
#> 6 C     (Text_E;Text_F) Text_4 Text_g
```

---

The aforesaid strategy works like this on your sample data

```
library(tidyverse)
#step-1
input1 <- example_df_2 %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~gsub(";(?![^(]*\\))", ";;", ., perl=TRUE)))

#step-2
map_dfc(input1, ~{max(map_int(input1, ~ length(unlist(str_split(., ';;'))) )) -> l1
  length(unlist(str_split(.x, ';;'))) -> tmp
  c(unlist(str_split(.x, ';;')), rep(NA, times = l1 - tmp))
}) %>% fill(everything())
#> # A tibble: 12 x 8
#>    deal_ids  acquirer_ids acquirer_names      acquirer_owners~ acquirer_country 
#>    <chr>     <chr>        <chr>               <chr>            <chr>            
#>  1 3020269MM "05MW2D-E"   "Cushman & Wakefie~ "Subsidiary"     "United States"  
#>  2 3137144MM " 060Y79-E"  " Ontario Teachers~ " Subsidiary"    " Canada"        
#>  3 3087938MM " 07HJ6C-E"  " Pacific Alliance~ " Subsidiary"    " Hong Kong"     
#>  4 3010412MM " 0FT58G-E"  " TPG Real Estate ~ " Subsidiary"    " United States" 
#>  5 3054942MM "0GVB8N-E"   "Jiangsu Aukura Sm~ "Public Company" "China (People's~
#>  6 441272MM  "05PYR2-E"   "City of Shanghai"  "Government"     "China (People's~
#>  7 441272MM  " 0H2MMQ-E"  " Hotels & Préfére~ " Subsidiary"    " France"        
#>  8 441272MM  "0H3CG6-E"   "Business Empire I~ "Subsidiary"     "British Virgin ~
#>  9 441272MM  "0JK2T2-E"   "Profit Sky Corp L~ "Subsidiary"     "Hong Kong"      
#> 10 441272MM  "05G8Z3-E"   "BAIN CAPITAL LLC"  "Private Compan~ "United States"  
#> 11 441272MM  " 05L112-E"  " Huawei Technolog~ " Private Compa~ " China (People'~
#> 12 441272MM  " 05L112-E"  " Huawei Technolog~ " Private Compa~ " China (People'~
#> # ... with 3 more variables: acquirer_size <chr>,
#> #   acquirer_secondary_industry <chr>, acquirer_synopsis <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>